# PostgreSQL, result to array

Tags: postgresql

In my program I have (almost) such a table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_list 
   (profilenum integer, profilename text, compid text) 
   ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO temp_list 
VALUES (1, 'bynamePROFILE_border_Minimal',       '03'),
       (2, 'bynamePROFILE_backoffice_Universal', '03'),
       (3, 'bynamePROFILE_calc_Universal',       '03'),
       (4, 'bynamePROFILE_calc_Universal',       '02'),
       (5, 'bynamePROFILE_backoffice_Minimal',   '01'),
       (6, 'bynamePROFILE_ilup_Universal',       '03');
```

I can query it like this:

```
SELECT profilename  
  FROM temp_list WHERE compid='03' AND profilename LIKE 'bynamePROFILE_%';
```

... what gives expected result.
But I need some string manipulation to get wanted strings suitable to lately cast to array form in my program:

```
SELECT array_agg(btrim(profilename, 'bynamePROFILE_')) 
  FROM temp_list WHERE compid='03' AND profilename LIKE 'bynamePROFILE_%';
```

This gives me incorrect result:

```
"{order_Minimal,ckoffice_Universal,calc_Universal,ilup_Universal}"  
 (note missing first letter(s) in words beginning with 'b')
```

instead of:

```
"{border_Minimal,backoffice_Universal,calc_Universal,ilup_Universal}"
```

Is this because of me (as usual) or because of PostgreSQL and can my query be improved somehow to get wanted result?

Windows 10/64, PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

> btrim(string text [, characters text])
>
> Remove the longest string consisting only of characters in *characters* (a space by default) from the start and end of string.

If you want to remove the prefix `abba`, the function `btrim()` is not a correct choice:

```
with my_table (str) as (
values
    ('abbababax')
)

select btrim(str, 'abba')
from my_table;

 btrim 
-------
 x
(1 row)
```

Use one of other string manipulation functions, e.g. `right()`:

```
with my_table (str) as (
values
    ('abbababax')
)

select right(str, -4)
-- or
-- select right(str, -length('abba'))
from my_table;

 right 
-------
 babax
(1 row)
```

Example of the use of regexp. Use `^` character to ensure you are removing the substring from the beginning of the string:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '^abba', '')
from my_table;
```

Comment: The best choice would probably be `regexp_replace`.

Comment: @jcaron - probably not, as regexp functions are more expensive.

Comment: I mean in terms of resistance to various inputs and later code changes. But of course it depends on how many rows are to be processed.

Comment: Good point about resistance to various inputs though it can be easily resolved, see the updated answer.

Comment: I see, thanks 'klin'. Would you belive me or not this code with btrim works in my program for a few past years :) Right string works OK. I would like to see example with regex replace too if possible.

Comment: Well, in many cases `btrim()` can work properly, it depends on the first character after the *prefix*. See the updated answer with `regexp_replace().`

Comment: OK, I see. And I also repair a program which now work reliable, thanks.